# Relation with many roles - Logical Model

Tags: database-design

I have an assignment where I am asked to draw a logical model. The data is for a hospital where each doctor can have three roles:

- supervises a patient
- requests for a procedure
- carries on a procedure

**My question is:**

How can I present this correctly? Should I have one relation with the name "DOCTOR", and draw three relationships, one for each role?

Answer (score 0):

You need one DOCTOR and another ROLES with one to many relationship with these two.  Here 1 DOCTOR will have more than one ROLES (may be only one active).

A role for a doctor may discontinued one the basis of date/active flag.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so I need to create a new relation ROLES and connect it to DOCTOR three times? because I also have to connect DOCTOR to PROCEDURE and ADMISSION according to the doctors roles. Thank you

Comment: "so I need to create a new relation ROLES and connect it to DOCTOR three times?" I think Yes.